# I have an error trying to run shopizer-inventory-xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml, shopizer

I am working with shopizer and I try to use https://github.com/shopizer-ecommerce/shopizer-inventory-csv to upload inventory from a csv file.

I edit . and the I run  ./mvnw clean install

But I am getting this error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project shopizer-inventory-csv: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.shopizer:shopizer-inventory-csv:jar:2.0.3-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.shopizer:sm-core-model:jar:2.0.3-SNAPSHOT, com.shopizer:sm-shop:jar:2.0.3-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.shopizer:sm-core-model:jar:2.0.3-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: are you connected to MAVEN repositories ? which ones and do they have com.shopizer artefacts ?

Comment: This is my configuration in pom.xml  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.shopizer/sm-core-model -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.shopizer</groupId>
      <artifactId>sm-core-model</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.3</version>
  </dependency>